# DateDiff everyday in an interval day to day

Tags: ms-access, vba

Let's say I have a StartDate: 02/02/2014 10:00 and EndDate :01/30/2014 15:00 is it possible to have this result in a query?

Comment: All you want is the difference between the two values, shown as hours?
Then datediff("h",#2/20/2014 11:00 AM#, Now())

Comment: not only a DateDiff, I need to show which days were within that range.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the dates you do have are in a table or not, but just by using a query, no, it is NOT possible.  If you have a table of dates, but there are gaps in the dates, then again, no, not possible.

If you are willing to invest the time in some VBA code, then YES, you can produce what you want. Assuming you have a form where you enter STARTDATE and ENDDATE, you could use the code below to create a table of dates, then set your query to LEFT JOIN (If you have another table):

```
Private Sub SomeButton_Click()
Dim strSQL  As String
Dim dDate As Date

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
' NOTE!!! Either create table manually, or comment out next two lines after first time!!!
strSQL = "CREATE TABLE tempDates (tDate DateTime);"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

strSQL = "delete * from tempDates"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

dDate = #1/1/2014#                  'Forms!frmYours!txtStartDate    ' Set starting date
Do While dDate < #3/1/2014#         'Forms!frmYours!txtEndDate      ' Set Ending date
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tempDates (tDate) SELECT '" & dDate & "' AS Expr1;"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
    dDate = dDate + 1
Loop
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```